# Static reflection of member functions of non-POD classes

Tags: c++, templates, reflection, variadic-templates, c++17

IIUC, nowadays one can easily do static reflection of POD classes/structs using, e.g., [boost::hana](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html) or [magic_get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get).

How can I perform similar static reflection of some member functions of non-POD classes? (I'm looking for a solution which doesn't require using a compiler fork which implements proposed static reflection extensions.)

In my specific use case, I have existing classes each having some setters. I'd like to wrap those classes with an adapter which pulls values of the appropriate types from some input generators and calls the matching setters on the adapted instance.

```
class A {
public:
   void setParam1(double); // To be annotated, e.g. REFLECT_MEM_FUNC(void setParam1(double);)
   void setParam2(Param);  // To be annotated, e.g. REFLECT_MEM_FUNC(void setParam2(Param);)
   void anotherFunc();     // Not annotated

private:
   double param1;
   Param param2;
// ...
};

class B {
public:
   void mySetParam(int);   // To be annotated, e.g. REFLECT_MEM_FUNC(void mySetParam(int);)

private:
   SomeOtherClass inner;   // parameter passed on to this member
// ...
};

template<
   typename AdaptedT, 
   // Tuple of references to classes, each implementing AppropriateParam get();
   // AppropriateParam return type of each getter must match the matching reflected setter.
   // To be clear, it's the instantiator's responsibility to provide matching Inputs; Inputs is not an auto-generated type since it can be anything providing the expected static interface.
   typename Inputs
> class Adapter {
public:
   Adapter(AdaptedT, Inputs);

   // Calls adapted's reflected setters with the values provided by inputs.
   setParametersFromInputs();

private:
   AdaptedT adapted;
   Inputs inputs;
// ... 
};

// Just to demonstrate the static interface expected from an input
template<typename ParamT>
class Input {
public:
   ParamT get();
// ...
};

Input<double> inputDouble { /* ... */ };
Input<Param>  inputParam { /* ... */ };
Adapted<A, std::tuple<Input<double>&, Input<Param>&>> adapter {
   { /* ... */ },
   {inputDouble, inputParam}
};

// Calls:
// adapted.setParam1(std::get<0>(inputs).get());
// adapted.setParam2(std::get<1>(inputs).get());
adapter.setParametersFromInputs();
```

Comment: "*IIUC, nowadays one can easily do static reflection of POD classes/structs using, e.g., boost::hana or magic_get.*" If by "easily", you mean "download and use gigantic template metaprogramming libraries", then yes.

Comment: C++ does not support static reflection in a meaningful sense of the term. The fact that there exist template tricks, that happen to work on some compilers today, that happen to let you do, in some situations, something that approximates static reflection does not change this.

Comment: @Barry Sure. I assumed that for the above specific case (reflection of specifically-annotated member functions), there would be C++17 standard-compliant template tricks (and possibly a library implementing them) which would allow performing it. I could be wrong.